# Auto fill radio button in volt template without using model

Tags: phalcon, volt

I rendered elements of a form in volt file using below code. I want to auto fill the default radio button.

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <div><label>Gender *:</label>
    <label class="radio-inline popup-gender">{{ element }}{{ element.label()}}:</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: nope......i did that differently.....

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP to prepare the form:

```
$radio = new Radio('my_radio', ['id' => null, 'value' => 'one']);
$radio->setDefault('one');
$form->add($radio);
$radio = new Radio('my_radio', ['id' => null, 'value' => 'two']);
$form->add($radio);
```

If you're using Volt:

```
{{ set_default('my_radio', 'one') }}
{{ radio_field('my_radio', ['id' => null, 'value' => 'one']) }}
{{ radio_field('my_radio', ['id' => null, 'value' => 'two']) }}
```